# How to connect to a Wifi that requests for a network security key using Windows Native Wifi Functions?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-8

I'm developing a way to connect to a Wifi using VS2010 and currently stuck on how to make it connect with a network security key. I am able to enumerate all the Wifi hotspot in my area and get their SSID, MAC addresses, etc using Windows Native Wifi Functions (WlanOpenHandle, WlanEnumInterfaces, WlanQueryInterface, WlanGetNetworkBssList). I've already read about `WlanConnect()` on MSDN but I'm still clueless. Can you give me some hints that would make the code connect to a Wifi that asks for a network security key?

Comment: Why?  If it's a network you've connected to before you can use a saved profile to connect.  If it's some random new network then you won't know the security key anyway.  What's the use case?  Maybe there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: @arx the use case is I wanted to connect to the Wifi I have not connected before and supply the security key (which I have the info) programmatically. So somewhere on the Wlan API, I must add this key as a parameter, I just have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have at least one saved Wifi connection run the command

`netsh wlan export profile`

This will export all your Wifi profiles as XML files in the current directory.

When you call `WlanConnect` you can supply a literal XML profile string in the `WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS` structure if `wLanConnectionMode` is set to `wlan_connection_mode_temporary_profile`.

If you can use the XML from one of your exported profiles to connect successfully to a secured network, then presumably you should be able to alter the XML and use the same technique to connect to new networks.

I've never tried this, and I've no idea what encoding is used for the key stored in the XML, but it seems like a possible way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an example profile to start with, as arx had suggested. 
When exporting a profile, add the key=clear arg. This will export the profile with the key in it. You can than see the setup that you would need to adjust.

Example : `netsh wlan export profile name=”<profileName>” folder=”<SaveLocation>” key=clear`

The resulting xml will contain a section with:

```
<MSM>
    <security>
        <authEncryption>
            <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
            <encryption>AES</encryption>
            <useOneX>false</useOneX>
        </authEncryption>
        <sharedKey>
            <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
            <protected>false</protected>
            <keyMaterial>YourPaswordTextHERE</keyMaterial>
        </sharedKey>
    </security>
</MSM>
```

So once you have your profile string, update the keyMaterial element with your programmatically obtained password. Once this is done you should be able to call wlanConnect.